# How do I approach asking what the pay review process is?

Tags: communication, performance-reviews, salary-review

I started a new job a few months ago, and neglected to ask during the interview process what their process for pay review and bonuses is.

Six months in and thinking about my value to the company - and I'm not sure whether the conversation about a payrise is going to come up naturally (ie after one year, or perhaps at the end of the year) or if I keep quiet and it just doesn't come up.

So I could ask my manager what the process is, but I'm worried that that will make them think that I'm thinking of leaving, and could be problematic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think asking for something you don't know portray a bad sign. You should know the aspects based on which you can make informed decisions.

You don'e necessarily mention that you missed / neglected this topic during the interview or onboarding process. Talk to your manager and say:

> *"Hey boss, I realized that I don't know enough about the pay revision process that is followed here. I want to know more about the process and I have some questions , is there a document / policy that I can refer, or shall I talk to you (or someone else who you think is better suited for this discussion) regarding that?"*

If they value you (or employees in general) and have a transparent process, they'll be happy to help you understand. Otherwise, if they become defensive and start asking counter-questions on why you need to know that - that's already a red flag for you, irrespective of what policy / process exists or not.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a good point, makes me feel more comfortable about things.